# Cubic spline interpolation in Python 2.2

Tags: python, interpolation, spline

I searched for a fast and easy way for a cubic spline interpolation with Python and found Scipy. The problem is that Scipy isn't compatible with the Python version 2.2 (I'm not able to change it!) but I also can't find any other library.

Little description: I have n amount of points which contains a X, Y and Z value. The values are not sorted by it's size!

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: How can you not upgrade your Python version, but you can install a library for it?

Comment: Problem is that the game I'm modifying is based on Python 2.2 that's why I can't upgrade to e.g. 2.7 but there's a lib folder I can add python libs.